# What was entering Grand Central Station like in 1943, especially interior?

Tags: united-states, world-war-two, transportation, new-york

I'd like a description of entering Grand Central Station and interior circa 1943, or at least information about what it looked like and/or what the experience would be like.

Comment: Here is a pictorial article, which includes photos of Grand Central Station from the 1940s: http://theweek.com/articles/468069/happy-centennial-12-oldtimey-photos-grand-central-terminal

Comment: @PeterDiehr: That's a fun find - Worth an upvote from me if you make it an answer.

Comment: If you go to the NY Public Library's Digital Collections page and search "Grand Central," you will be able to get lots of images (plenty of which are from the period you mention). http://digitalcollections.nypl.org/

Answer (score 3):

[Happy centennial! 12 old-timey photos of Grand Central Terminal](http://theweek.com/articles/468069/happy-centennial-12-oldtimey-photos-grand-central-terminal)

[image]

**In wartime: The main concourse is crowded with people on Dec. 14, 1941, during the unveiling of a government mural above the mezzanine level that encouraged Americans to buy savings bonds and stamps in support of the war. Down the hallway to the right, an archway points travelers toward the nearest telegraph — how quaint! (AP Photo)**